# inputing char for a symmetric cipher to be used in a game

Tags: c++, game-engine

I am looking for a simple function that would allow an user (player) to assign letters of the alphabet to other letters. For example: "a = n" . Then placing theses letters in an array: alb[n,..]. Should I use pointers?

Comment: You need to be a *lot* more specific in your question. Plus, provide details on what you've tried/researched. Also, post code.

Comment: What do you think you should use? What are the pros and cons of pointers in your opinion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the answer. Here some test code that uses the first three letters of the alphabet.

```
int i = 0, j = 0;
string alp[] = { "a", "b", "c" }, alpc[] = { "0", "1", "2" };

while (i <= 2) {
    cout << "Enter the letter substitution: " << alp[i] << " = ";
    cin >> alpc[i];
    for (j = 0; j < i; ++j) {
        while (alpc[j] == alpc[i]) {
            cout << "Please enter a non-redundant letter substitution: ";
            cin >> alpc[i];
        }

    }
    ++i;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

use std::vector

Place to start, think what the translate function would look like. That tells you the shape of the data you need. Initially hard code the translation table in a test program otherwise you will get distracted with worrying about talking to the user.

Once you understand the tx table you will need and how t store it then worry about inputting it.